# set identity field in sybase such that if a row gets deleted, the value os identity column should be reused

Tags: sybase, identity

I have one identity column. suppose the last row has these values
9    asd       india
where 9 is the identity column value.
Now if i am deleting this row and inserting another row, the next identity value will be 10 and not 9.
I know there is some way (settings) to make it the other way but cant find it.
Any help please..

Comment: Sybase is a company, not a product.  Which specific Sybase database product are you asking about?

Answer (score 0):

you can use set identity_update ON

first you have to set identity_update  ON ,then you have to write a update statement which will update the identity column value.

as per it you can change the value 10 to 9.

Hope this will help you out..!!!

Comment: can this be used in sybase?

Comment: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1572/html/commands/X64136.htm go through this link